# Bash TorSocks Issue

Tags: bash, shell, curl, tor, torsocks

In theory, my goal with this script is to randomly generate .onion urls and check whether they exist or not.  Basically, the *status* variable is sending a HEAD request then returning the response.  *head* grabs the first line from the response then grep searches for the HTTP header within that first line sending the output to /dev/null.  If all goes well, *status* should be set to true.  I use an if statement to check if *status* is true.  If it is true, then I output "this service exists" while if *status* is not true, "this service does not exist" is outputted.

The problem is, torsocks returns an error if the onion url does not exist.

The error is:

```
[Jul 03 17:09:23] ERROR torsocks[4422]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:516)
```

I verified that the command does indeed work on legitimate existing onion urls meaning that the error is something to do with torsocks quite obviously.

Anyone know of a solution or possible fix?  I could not find anything helpful.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="http://"$(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 16 | head -n 1)".onion";
echo "[i] Scanning $url";
status=$(torsocks curl -s --head $url | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23].." > /dev/null);
if $status; then
    echo "[+] Valid hidden service $url";
else
    echo "[-] Invalid hidden service $url";
fi
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @shellter, well, user intent appears to include filtering for 200 and 300-series responses, meaning we want to fail on 4xx or 5xx, so we'd at least need to add the `--fail` argument to `curl`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : yes, you're right.

Comment: I wrote something similar in Python and it is currently iterating through all possible .onion domains using the httping command instead of curl which seems to save a little bit of overhead. Good luck to you.

Comment: @jamescampbell I started off making this in Python, but it became problematic for me.  I'll definitely be needing to implement threading or multiprocessing to this bash script as it is currently iterating through no more than 100 onions per minute.  Good luck to you as well.

Comment: You are generating too much addresses. Tor uses Base32 for onion addresses. Furthermore not every hidden service is http based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never assigning `status` any non-empty value at all.

```
value=$(something >/dev/null)
```

...*throws away the output of `something`* (that's what the `>/dev/null` does), and thus will always unconditionally assign an empty string to `value` (since `$(...)` -- command substitution -- captures *output*, not *exit status*).

Moreover, you *aren't* throwing away error messages, because those are on stderr (FD 2), not stdout (FD 1).

---

Making some guesses at intent, perhaps you want instead:

```
if torsocks curl --fail --head "$url" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "[+] Valid hidden service $url";
else
    echo "[-] Invalid hidden service $url";
fi
```